# How to use data from a file in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, external-files

I am using TikZ and I want to produce several graphs from a data file. The file contains many lines with three numbers `x y r`. I want to use each line and draw a circle with `\draw (\x,\y) circle(\r);` where `\x`, `\y` and 
`\r` have been assigned the values read on a line. Is there a way to make a `\foreach`-like loop to make this ? I could change the lines into `x/y/z` if necessary to run something like

```
\foreachline \x/\y/\r in {filename} {
   \draw (\x,\y) circle(\r);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use something like `datatool` or `csvsimple` if you wanted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.csv}
1, 2, 3
4, 5, 2
3, 1, 4
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage{tikz,csvsimple}

\begin{document}

\csvreader[no head]{\jobname.csv}{1=\first, 2=\second, 3=\third}%
  {\tikz \draw (\first, \second) circle (\third);
    \par
    FYI, I used these numbers: \first, \second, \third.
    \par}

\end{document}
```